# Como fazer um ranking dos melhores compradores através do Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela em Excel com 15 mil linhas. Cada uma dessas linhas significa um produto vendido.

O layout está assim:

```
Produto - Nome do comprador - Valor do produto
```

Eu preciso fazer um ranking das cinco pessoas que mais gastaram dinheiro na empresa.

Para isso, eu preciso efetuar um cálculo que some a quantidade de 'nome do comprador' que há e some o valor das compras, somando a coluna 'valor do produto'.

Ou seja, se existe um cadastro João da Silva, eu preciso saber se ele comprou mais de uma vez e qual foi o valor total de produtos que ele comprou.

Eu pensei em usar o PROCV, mas não sei como fazer essa conta. Pois, além de eu preciso que haja uma ligação entre o nome e quanto a pessoa gastou na loja.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de que fórmula eu poderia utilizar?

Answer (score 3):

As tabelas dinâmicas podem ser utilizadas.

#### Solução

Com uma tabela como no exemplo a seguir:

```
| Produto | Nome do Comprador | Valor do produto |
|---------|-------------------|------------------|
| A       | João              | R$ 30,00         |
| B       | João              | R$ 20,00         |
| A       | Maria             | R$ 15,00         |
| C       | Enzo              | R$ 40,00         |
| B       | Enzo              | R$ 19,00         |
| D       | José              | R$ 35,00         |
| E       | Valentina         | R$ 45,00         |
| D       | Joana             | R$ 35,00         |
| A       | Joana             | R$ 29,00         |
```

Selecionar os dados da tabela e "Inserir" -> "Tabela Dinâmica"

[image: Tabela Dinâmica]

Nos campos da tabela dinâmica selecionar o "Nome do Comprador" e "Valor do Produto"

E em valores, selecionar a opção de Soma.

[image: Campos]

No filtro selecionar "Mais Opções de Classificação..."

[image: Filtro]

Nas opções de classificação selecionar em ordem "Decrescente (de Z a A) por:"

e o item "Soma de Valor de produto"

[image: Opções de Classificação]

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 2):

Faça assim:

1. Crie uma aba nova.
2. Nessa aba nova, faça uma coluna de nomes únicos dos compradores lá da sua aba original (dica de fonte de ajuda: https://www.extendoffice.com/pt/documents/excel/1627-excel-extract-unique-values-from-list.html)
3. Faça outra coluna com as somas por comprador, usando a função SOMASE para cada item único da coluna criada no item 2 (dica de fonte de ajuda: https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-somase-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).
4. Ordene os valores pela coluna de soma em ordem decrescente. Esse é o seu ranking.

Comment: Podes acrescentar uma coluna para saberes quantas vezes cada pessoa realizou compras na empresa. `=CONTAR.SE(..`